# How to remove input field layout

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I have this Primefaces calendar with custom skin:

[image]

[image]

It turns out that the input filed is also overwritten by the Primefaces skin. This is the css file of the Primefaces skin: http://pastebin.com/yiJ1YjUx

Can you tell me how I can remove the input filed layout - I want just basic white input filed?

Comment: You want to remove input filed of Calendar component ?

Comment: I want to remove the css layout of the input field - just default white input filed.

Comment: You can override css class of calendar component.

Comment: View my answer, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
<style type="text/css">
                #test{
                    background-color: magenta !important;
                }
            </style>
            <p:inputText id="test"/>
```

Calendar use input component to get input from user and it place input tag inside span tag, so you can custom calendar(not affect to all input):

```
            <style type="text/css">
                span input{
                    background-color: blue !important;
                }
            </style>
```

Comment: I have just tested, it just display white input field.

Comment: It's not working properly - the input filed is till black and the calendar is not displayed when I click on the input field.

Comment: oh, so sorry, i understand your problem, Calendar component use input to get input, so you need to create your own component, or you set custom css to each input(see updated anwser).

Comment: To create your own component, you create new composite component and set custom css to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply hide an input using CSS, you can do it with the property:

```
.your-input-class {
    display: none;
}
```

Using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(".your-input-class").hide();
```

But this makes sense only if you can not work with the html code of your calendar.